# how to show a:hover color in gmail

Tags: html, css, gmail

i want to send a html email to  gmail email box. how to show a:hover color ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gmail strips the styles in the head of the document so you can't actually specify a hover color.

Look at this comparison to see what is supported : http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/